# IBM bladecenter blade IMM logs

Tags: ibm, ipmi, bladecenter, hs22

We have an IBM bladenter H with heterogeneous blades running RHEL 6.

Is it possible to download and clear the **on-blade IMM** logs via IBM supplied command line tools such as `ipmitool`, `asu`, `dsa` or other tools? It can be programmatic or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

From the blade, telnet to the IMM, log in and run `clearlog`.